# phpmyadmin timing out when accessing via public IP on AWS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin, lamp

I need some tech help. I'm a total noob with the `linux/aws` environment. I'm trying to install the `LAMP stack on` and `Ubuntu 14.04 aws image` and when I try and access `phpMyAdmin` via the public IP it times out.

I added phpMyAdmin to the `/usr/share/ folder` and added and alias pointing to the phpadmin file in the share folder to the `000-default.conf` file in the `apache2 folder`.

I haven't been able to find any answers online so I'm turning to you all. I'm using `phpMyAdmin 4.6/php 7.0/mysql 5.7.8/Apache 2.4.7`. port 80 is open and subnets have been added and mapped.

Any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the Apache logs?

Comment: no I'm sure where to find them.  I'm a total noob with this environment. I found this in the error folder:  ubuntu@ip-172-31-26-149:/usr/share/apache2/error$ dir
contact.html.var                     HTTP_PRECONDITION_FAILED.html.var
HTTP_BAD_GATEWAY.html.var            HTTP_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE.html.var
HTTP_BAD_REQUEST.html.var            HTTP_REQUEST_TIME_OUT.html.var
HTTP_FORBIDDEN.html.var              HTTP_REQUEST_URI_TOO_LARGE.html.var
HTTP_GONE.html.var                   HTTP_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.html.var

Comment: HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.html.var  HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED.html.var
HTTP_LENGTH_REQUIRED.html.var        HTTP_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE.html.var
HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED.html.var     HTTP_VARIANT_ALSO_VARIES.html.var
HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var              include
HTTP_NOT_IMPLEMENTED.html.var        README

Comment: Probably the error log is in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`